# Is cap coming off too easily?

Tags: oil, valve-cover

Honda Civic coupe vti 1999.

I bought this replacement cap and fitted it.  Unlike the stock or other caps it doesn’t have a asteroid shape so it’s harder to screw down.

Anycase I screwed it in but I notice i can take it off with my left hand using a little bit of pressure.  I tried to tighten more but as there’s no grip seems difficult.

Just wondering if it’s safe to use this cap on any car whenever I take the oil filler cap off I usually find I need to use a lot of pressure.  If this is coming off with my left hand(I’m right handed) and a little bit of pressure is there something wrong? As I say there’s not much grip to keep tightening.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you can put a long bar through the holes and get it mega tight.

Comment: With all those holes in it, it looks like a (supposedly) cool looking weight-saving gizmo intended for car modders or wannabe race car drivers, not for "normal use."

Comment: If it comes off with a little bit of pressure it's not going to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you feel it needs tightening a little, then put a long screwdriver all the way through the holes and tighten it.  Don’t overdo it though.  You will then need to make sure you have a screwdriver handy in case you need to remove it.

Comment: @JamesWilson - And if you attached the o-ring as I suggested and you do this, you'll tear it from the cap. If you're feeling any resistance when you un-tighten the cap, more than likely it is tight enough. +1 Howie, as this is about as good of an answer as someone can give.

Comment: Maybe this cap would have "felt right" in terms of resistance before you decided the O-ring wasn't fitted correctly and "redesigned" it. But it's too late to find out now.